# Is there a list containing regular graphs in GAP?

Tags: graph-theory, gap

I'm trying to write a function in GAP (this is the first time I am using it) and I want to loop through like the "first" $1000$ non-complete, non-empty regular graphs. Do I have to construct this function or is it included in GRAPE (I didn't find it). 
Furthermore: if I have to construct this list is there an efficient way to generate non-isomorphic regular graphs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There is a tool, geng, in the nauty package which will generate regular graphs quickly enough; my understanding is that the nauty stuff is accessible in GAP.

Comment: Were you referring to some easy way to generate all regular graphs with built in function or that if I have generated all, then I can reduce the list with geng to non-isomorphic ones?

Comment: The graphs that geng produces are not isomorphic - it gives you one graph from each isomorphism class.